# How do I specify negative/false command line switches in Simian Analyzer?

Tags: powershell, simian

The [Simian Analyzer](http://www.harukizaemon.com/simian/index.html) can be invoked like this

```
simian-2.5.1.exe *.cs
```

which will launch it with all its default settings. Some of its flags/switches/options are Boolean and set to "true" as default. See [here](http://www.harukizaemon.com/simian/features.html) for the complete list.

But how do I, in Powershell, set the true-switches to false? That is, how do I specify that `ignoreIdentifierCase` should be false?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The option should be postfixed with either a "+" (for true) or a "-" (for false).
So the answer is:

```
simian-2.5.1.exe -ignoreIdentifierCase- *.cs
```

(with the minus-sign *after* "ignoreIdentifierCase")